# How do I turn off verbose mode when sourcing .cshrc?

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, tcsh

I am using tcsh as my default shell.  I have a generic .cshrc file that I've used for years on several different systems, including the last version of OS X.  Now with OS X El Capitan, when I open the Terminal app and the .cshrc file is sourced, all non-comment lines in the .cshrc file are echoed to the screen as if I had `#!/bin/csh -x` at the top of the file, which I don't.  I would like to turn that verbose mode off.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't happen for my `.cshrc` (perhaps some stray setting).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas.  Yes, this is very strange and I'm at a loss.  Was just wondering if anyone else had seen this.  I ported my home account config files from the last OS X (.login, .cshrc, .exrc, .vimrc) here and like I said above, this didn't happen with the last OS X.  No biggie, I can live with it.

Comment: are the commands also echoed if you run `source .cshrc`? what's the output of `tcsh --help`? perhaps try setting your default shell to `tcsh` again using `chsh`..

Comment: Hi shx2.  Yes the commands are echoed when I run source .cshrc

Comment: Thanks for the reply @shx2.  Yes the .cshrc file commands are echoed when I run "source .cshrc".  Running "tcsh --help" gives the list of available flags.  I wonder if when I changed my shell from the default bash to tcsh, it installed as tcsh -X?  Interesting point.  I just tried setting the default shell again using "chpass -s /bin/tcsh <user>" and I get the same problem.  Also, I just noticed that all command line commands are echoed before execution so it's definitely defaulting to tcsh -X.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Try adding `unset echo` as the first and/or last command in your .cshrc. Try the same thing with `unset verbose`

Comment: Thx @shx2.  Both of those had no effect when added to the .cshrc file.  I then tried adding them to the .login file and `unset echo` removed the echo from my command line commands which is the main thing I wanted to fix.  The echo of the .cshrc file commands I can live with.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Depending on your system try to look system level .cshrc and .login files.

Comment: For osx El Capitan you can look at /etc/csh.cshrc and /etc/csh.login.

Comment: Thx Sung.  I'll check those out.

Comment: Hi Sung.  Those only contain prompt and path settings but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I would like to set verbose mode.